# Probability of equation

Tags: probability

Two numbers $a$ & $b$ are randomly selected from the interval $(0,1]$. Find the probability that the equation $ax^2+bx+1=0$ will have real solutions.

I suppose that $b^2-4a \ge 0$ implies that the solutions are real. But how to find the probability from here?

Comment: You mean $b^2-4a$.  Also, you should enclose the MathJax in $ signs in order to get it formatted correctly.

Comment: Yes i mean that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$b^2-4a\ge0\implies a\le \frac{b^2}4$$ so the probability is $$\int_0^1\frac{b^2}4\,db=\left[\frac{b^3}{12}\right]_0^1=\frac1{12}$$

Answer (score 2):

I assume by "randomly selected" you mean the selection is uniformly random.

For the solutions to be real we require $b^2 - 4a \geq 0$, i.e., $a \leq \frac{b^2}4$. Plotting $a$ and $b$ on the $y$ and $x$ axes, respectively, of the $(0,1] \times (0,1]$ region, the area of real solutions is the area under the curve $y = \frac{x^2}4$. The probability is the ratio of this area to the area of the whole region.